# How to concatenate bytesio object in python?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, bytesio

I created a main bytesIO object that will concatenate additional bytesIO object.

```
csv_file = BytesIO

    for _ in range(iterations):
        sliced_queryset = queryset[start_index:end_index]
        serialized = serializer(sliced_queryset, many=True)
        partial_csv_file = write_to_csv(...some arguments)
        csv_file.write(partial_csv_file)
```

I'm iterating over a queryset and constructing a csv file bytesIO object for each iteration. `partial_csv_file` is a bytesIO object. I want to concatenate it to the `csv_file` object and output a main csv_file object at the end.

The issue is calling `csv_file.write(partial_csv_file)` returns an error `*** TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

If I pass in `csv_file.write(partial_csv_file.read())`, it complains that it expects a string object.

How can I combine bytesIO object to form a single csv_file object?

Comment: `csv_file = BytesIO` doesn't create a BytesIO *object*, it merely creates another name for the BytesIO class itself.  You want `csv_file = BytesIO()`.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah I realized that was my mistake. Thanks!